# Schedule activities in sql server

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to set a query (SQL SERVER) in order to create a later Gantt in PowerBI, the query calls activities for different projects and some activities can only exist if another one is already done, my query shows something like this:

```
Father Activity | Son Activity 
1               | 2
3               | 4
4               | 5
5               | 6
5               | 7
```

The first row would be no problem, cause Act 2 is the last one, but in other cases, the Act 4 is son of the Act 3 and father of Act 5, the inner levels are really deep. I need to create a single row that got all the path from the last activity showing just 3 rows creating the neccessary columns for the n sons:

```
ID  Act1 Act2 Act3 Act4 ... Actp
1    1    2    NA   NA
2    3    4    5    6
3    3    4    5    7
```

Thank you, I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: So really this question is about how to represent a Gantt chart in Power BI? I suggest you look at third party controls for that requirement.

Comment: Already had the party control, but I need the data ordered in a single row per activity with all the path.

Comment: So would the resulting dataset have one column? or one column per activity? One column is straightforward. Many columns is not.

Comment: One additional column per father activity, every row is a single activity

Comment: Can you edit your sample output dataset indicating column names and values. In your existing sample you'll have four columns, and the data in the first two rows and last two columns will be blank?

Comment: Done! the total columns will be defined with the largest path from the sample, the activities that got less than the total, should be filled with blanks.

Comment: Is this the type of dataset that your  thrid party control accepts - a table with a dynamic number of columns?

Comment: Yes, I need that kind of dataset, the number of columns will be defined at the end of the largest path, doesn't have te be dynamic.

Comment: The largest path might be different every time you run it though. It's easiest if you nominate a large number (50?) and fix the columns at that. Basically to get what you want you'd need a recursive CTE to walk down the tree and assign a level, then you'd need to use `pivot` to pivot that out to columns.